# Perguntas que pedem a diferença de uma coisa com outra e gera múltiplas perguntas

Tags: debate

Eis um caso recente:

[Qual a diferença de função e diretiva?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/197232/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-diretiva)

Outro dia vi um bem parecido mas deixei quieto pois perguntava a diferença de X com Y. Eram apenas duas coisas.

Nesse caso acima pede para explicar diversas coisas como funções, diretivas, módulos, bibliotecas. Eu acho que isso ficou amplo demais, dando motivo para fechamento. Mas tenho dúvida se realmente deve fechar ou podemos tolerar.
Para mim são múltiplas perguntas numa só. Mas é confuso saber se devo tolerar ou não.

Comment: Eu concordo contigo quanto ao sinalizar como ampla demais as perguntas que são, na verdade, muitas em uma só. Neste caso em específico, parece que ocorreu isso porque o AP parece não fazer muita ideia do que está perguntando.

Answer (score 5):

Não ficou amplo porque na verdade só uma precisava ser respondida o resto era duplicata. Não deveria fechar porque uma dúvida era pertinente.

Esta foi minha interpretação para **este caso específico**.

Comment: Também penso isso. Então dá para tolerar, eu acho. Um problema é ter conflito em como outros interpretam. rsr  Vamos ver no que vira.